# Shopware 6 - prices modified with decorator does not function correctly in product price filter

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I used the example AbstractProductPriceCalculator from the developer page, to dynamically modify a product's price from whatever was entered in Admin into say 1EUR. This all works just fine. The product sorting Price asc/desc works too.

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/customize-price-calculation

But the price range filter on default Storefront does not work, this still think the product has the price that was entered in Admin - not the decorated price.

Is there another way to dynamically set prices such they function with the filters too?

Any hints appreciated

[image]

Comment: I just followed this blog https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/customize-price-calculation
to add decorator to modify price, but it is not working. How did you do it? the last line call the original calculate() method so it show the original data.

Answer (score 2):

The price filter is generated from `SalesChannelProductEntity::cheapestPrice`, so make sure to also change this, as indicated in the docs.